# how to write parameter sanitiser method to sanitize the parameters of other model in devise sign_up action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, devise, sanitization

i am having two tables employee , and company. i want to register the company name of an employee while Employee is registering by using the devise sign_up action. how to write devise parameter sanitiser method to save the company name while an employee is registering?

Comment: Add your models code. And do you have your own `registrations_controller`?

Comment: yes, i generated the devise registration controller. how to override this controller so that while signup i can save employee details in employee table. and company details in companies table?  and how to write devise sign_up view for saving company field? i am  having the has many association between employee and company.  company has many employees.

Comment: Please post the code for `registrations_controller`.

Comment: i  just executed   `rails generate devise:controllers Employee` command and    generated the  devise controllers. i did not wrote anything in that. as i don t  know how to override that. here i got struck for knowing this only, i am posting the question :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is using [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) and overriding the `sign_up_params` method on the registrations controller.

#### 1. Set up the User model to accept attributes for company

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

#### 2. Override the default Registrations controller

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }
end
```

---

```
# app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # GET /users/sign_up
  def new
    @user = User.new(company: Company.new)
  end

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(
      :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
      company_attributes: [:name]
    )
  end
end
```

By digging into the [source of `Devise::RegistrationsController`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/868d3d82a014509167ccd7dd3e794171011bffe1/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L15) we can se that it calls `build_resource(sign_up_params)` which is about equivalent to `User.new(sign_up_params)`. So we can simply add our own params handling by declaring our own `sign_up_params` method.

Note that in `sign_up_params`we use the built Rails 4 strong parameter handling instead of the Devise sanitized params which is a home rolled solution that predates Rails 4. It might be possible to do it with Devise sanitized params but there is no real reason unless you have to have backwards compatibility with Rails 3.

#### 3. Customize the Registration form

To get the correct params hash we want the company name input to have the following `name` attribute:

```
user[company_attributes][name]
```

Rails has a nice helper called `fields_for` which lets us do that:

```
<%# app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb %>
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Company</legend>

    <%= f.fields_for :company do |c| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= c.label :name %><br />
        <%= c.text_field :name%>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </fieldset>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Notice that `fields_for` gives us a new form builder instance in the block (`c`) which we create our nested inputs from.

#### 4. Beer.

Comment: company is having many employees. not the employee is having many companies. your answer will work for the association where employee is having many companies but that is not the association here.

Comment: Dude, what are you talking about? This is exactly how you would do it if user belongs_to or has_one company

Comment: Its not an array of companies, its an array of parameters to whitelist. Read the rails guide on strong parameters

Comment: ok,  and how the devise employee view should  look like? and what should be the devise registrations controller code to be written to save the company column in company field?

Comment: I edited the answer with a full explaination. The devise parameter sanitizer does not accept nested hashes like the Rails 4 strong parameters as I wrongly assumed so the answer is quite different.

Answer (score 0):

for adding custom info in sign_up form Try this :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up)  { |u| u.permit( :company_name, :email,:password, :password_confirmation ) }
  end
end
```

and change in your views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :company_name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: company name field is not present in the devise(employee) table. it is having in companies table.  company has many employees. i am having has many Association.